# Django display a checkbox from DB. (Not forms)

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates, radio-button

I use bootstrap-tables plugin to show my 9000 row data with proper pagination. I have 2 Radiobox fields. 
 1.is_new 
 2.is_valid
I have a form, which displays these two fields with proper form widgets and the form values are captured when user selects something and it gets saved in DB, no issues.

But the problem is if I show 100 rows in a page, I have to retrieve the radiobox values from the DB, and to show it checked with "Yes" or "NO" as per that row's data. Here is the problem, I wrote Jquery inside $document.ready() for the same, it is happening for all the 100 rows but as the page loads, only the 100th row has the checked values. All the other checkboxes values are lost.

If someone can help me in solving this, it would be great. I want to show checked values w.r.t to database values in the django templates.

**forms.py**

```
CHOICES = (
   ('1', 'Yes'),
   ('0', 'No'),
 )

is_new = forms.ChoiceField(required=True,
                 choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer,),
            )
```

**showteams.html**

```
{% for team in teams %}
    ....
    ......

<td id="is_new">
{{form.is_new }}   // This shows the checkbox from Forms. 

{% if team.is_new%}

// Trying to set "Yes" Radiobox as checked if the value from DB is 1.
$('input[type="radio"][name="is_new"][value="1"').prop('checked', true)

{%else%}
// Trying to set "No" Radiobox as checked if the value from DB is 0.
$('input[type="radio"][name="is_new"][value="0").prop('checked', true)

{%endif%}

</td >
```

Comment: Are you going to show relevant code?

Comment: @duffn Please see my edited post. I have tried showing some relevant code.

Comment: Are you using one HTML form for all that checkboxes? or you're going without form at all?

Comment: @GwynBleidD Hey Initially I had a single form for the whole page and used post.getlist to get all checkboxes values. Now am using single form for each row and an ajax submit, the moment few changes are made in that row.

Comment: can you update your question to contain also your html forms in stage that javascript is not working?